# WPF register a function as a dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm still learning wpf and I'm trying to create my own control but I'm having a problem to register a function as a dependencyProperty

Let's say I have my control, I want the user to specify a function for the OnChange event of my control, I tried the following

```
    public readonly static DependencyProperty OnChangeProperty;

    public delegate void DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(Object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    public DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler Change;


    OnChangeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OnChange", typeof(DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler), typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler OnChange
    {
        get { return (DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler)GetValue(OnChangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OnChangeProperty, value); }
    }

    <my:MyControl OnChange="Control_OnChange"/>
```

But It didn't work, It gives me an XAML parse exception when it encounters "Control_OnChange", can anyone point me in the right direction ? I didn't find any answer for this question in MSDN or SO, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot register a function as a dependency property. You should [Create a Custom Routed Event](http://wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html):

```
// Register the routed event
public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectedEvent = 
EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent( "Selected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyCustomControl));

// .NET wrapper
public event RoutedEventHandler Selected
{
    add { AddHandler(SelectedEvent, value); } 
    remove { RemoveHandler(SelectedEvent, value); }
}
```

Then you can raise the event in your `UserControl`:

```
// Raise the routed event "selected"
RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MyCustomControl.SelectedEvent));
```

Then you can add a handler to the event:

`<my:MyCustomControl Selected="Control_OnSelected"/>`